# How can I add new data to an Arraylist & How can I remove user input duplicates?

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

What i am shooting for is to be able to take the input from my text field in my GUI and put it into an ArrayList. Then I need to check the array and see if I already have the Integer in the array. If so I need to remove both Integers so the Integer is no longer inside the array. I also need to be able to add the Integer if it is not a duplicate to the ArrayList.

The purpose of this is to be able to have users sign in with a number. The vision I have is for them to put their unique number in when they sign in or sign out (Like a time clock). If their number is not in the array, they are signing in. If their number is in the arraylist then they are signing out.

This is what i have for code so far, i am getting a problem with signing out. It keeps sending the second value in the array back as the only one able to sign out. I have tried fixing it and can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Let me know if it would be more helpful if i posted my whole program or if this code snippet is enough to figure it out.

Thanks,

```
private void btnSignInActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    // Get data from form and put it into an Array List
    Integer txtUserSignInName = Integer.valueOf(txtUserSignIn.getText());
    ArrayList<Integer> userSignInNumber = new ArrayList();
    userSignInNumber.add(12345678); //sample data
    userSignInNumber.add(55489563); //sample data
    userSignInNumber.add(26489564); //sample data
    userSignInNumber.add(78654865); //sample data
    userSignInNumber.add(txtUserSignInName);

    // Setting up HashSet so no duplicate data
    Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
    hashSet.addAll(userSignInNumber);
    userSignInNumber.clear();
    userSignInNumber.addAll(hashSet);

    // Other settings needed
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    String time = df.format(new Date());

    if ((txtUserSignIn.getText() != null && txtUserSignIn.getText().isEmpty())) {
        String userSignInErrorMessage = "Sorry, Please Try Again";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), userSignInErrorMessage, "Incorrect Sign In",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        //setting focus
        txtUserSignIn.setText("");
        txtUserSignIn.requestFocus();
    } else {
        for(int i = 1; i < userSignInNumber.size(); i++) {
            // If number is already in array, remove it
            if(txtUserSignInName.equals(userSignInNumber.get(i))) {
                userSignInNumber.remove((Integer)txtUserSignInName);
                System.out.println(txtUserSignInName + " has signed out");
                txtLoggedInUsers.append(txtUserSignInName + " has signed out at " + time + "\n");
                break;
            } else { // If number is not in the array, add it to the array
                System.out.println(txtUserSignInName + " has signed in");
                txtLoggedInUsers.append(txtUserSignInName + " has signed in at  " + time + "\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(userSignInNumber);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are not really suitable for what you are trying to do. You would be better off using one of the [Set interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementations. Sets provide *fast* [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)/[add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-)/[remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) methods that you can use, without generally having to iterate over all elements manually in a loop. And if you *do* need to quickly iterate over all elements for some reason, then a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) would work just fine. For example:

```
Set<Integer> signedIn = new LinkedHashSet<>();
...
if (signedIn.add(loginNumber)) {
    // The set was modified, therefore this is a new login
} else {
    // The number was already present, log-off the user.
    signedIn.remove(loginNumber);
}
...
if (signedIn.contains(loginNumber)) {
    // Allow the user to...
} else {
    // Error, user not signed in
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to be working so much better than what i had originally planned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your implementation.

The loop starts at `1` when array indices start at `0`, so you are skipping the first entry.

Then you always `break` out of the loop straight away after checking the 2nd item and so don't check any others.

A better approach would be to use a `Set`, not just to remove duplicates, but as a primary way to store who is signed in. Then you can check if a number is in the set easily with the `contains` method so you don't need to loop through manually (which means you don't have to deal with the problems associated with removing items from a list while you are looping through it).